# Find only text files in directory

Tags: linux, shell, find

I tried using this:

```
      $ find . -type f -exec file {} \;
        ./alma: ASCII text
        ./jaj.C: C source, ASCII text
        ./repa: ASCII text, with escape sequences
        ./mas.cpp: C++ source, ASCII text
        ./capa: ASCII text
        ./valami: ASCII text
```

But if it's a cpp file for example it still writes text so I can't use grep to exclude binary files....what should I do?

Comment: `cpp` file is a text file, why do you want to exclude it?

Comment: `.cpp` is text just the same as `.c`.  Why exclude `.cpp` when you are including `.c`?

Comment: well aren't c and cpp files binary files?I would like to exclude them

Comment: No, just as `file` says, they are ASCII text.

Comment: @ReggieKapros You can look at the in a text editor and they are readable (non-garbage)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the fast method to do it:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -print
```

`-I` in grep will ignore binary files, text files will match right away because of `.` (any character match), grep will give success for matched file, so `-print` from `find` will print the filename.

Comment: It should be noted that this will not find empty files.